# How can I center my content only when there are even items inside

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created this codepen.

https://codepen.io/Andrej888/pen/gOmpVmM

So I have one row with three columns inside. But I am creating these columns dynamically. Sometimes the number of the columns could be even or odd.

When they are even they look nice.

https://codepen.io/Andrej888/pen/oNZXKGv

But when they are odd like in the first example, the third column is in the middle under the first row and it looks ugly. How can I prevent this from happening?

How can I detect when there are odd numbers of columns in the rows, to make only that row to be default - flex-start instead justify content - so in my case whole row will be centered, but the
`THIRD COLUMNS WILL BE UNDER THE FIRST`?

Comment: Remove **justify-content-center** from `<div class="row justify-content-center">`. Then this will be looks good. Is this you need?

Comment: No, i need justify-content-center when i have even elements, but i don't need that class when i have odd elements

Comment: May I know why you need `justify-content-center` for even elements?

Comment: To center the content in the row ? I explained that when tthere are odd elements just the third one in the middle looks ugly ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your class to `justify-content-between`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-6 red">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 red">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 red">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```